# Add dynamic option selection list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add selection menu dynamically.That means when user select on option from selection menu it add new new selection menu and when user select option from new selection  menu, it should again add new option menu.

Here I have tried using Jquery. but it double selection menu. and it only work for first selection menu.how can I change this code to meet my requirement?.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(function ($) {
                $('.target').change(function () {
                    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                        $('#other').append('<select class="target"><option value="3" selected="selected">option1</option><option value="4" selected="selected">option2</option>  </select>');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input class="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
            <select class="target">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <div id="other"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the new `select` same as the original?

Answer (score 2):

use on delegated event for dynamically added element

```
$(document).on('change','.target',function() {
     $("select option:selected").each(function () {
         $('#other').append('<select class="target"><option value="3" selected="selected">option1</option><option value="4" selected="selected">option2</option>  </select>');
  });
});
```

delegating it to document works..however , it is recommeneded to delegate it to the closest static parent container  performancewise.

Comment: :Thanks for the answer: but still I'm having problem. this always double the previous selection menu. i need to add only one selection menu add when last selection menu option select? can you help me to solve that one?

Comment: can I change new selection list dynamically?

Comment: yes you can... change it in option element inside the append... and didn't get you first comments..

Comment: You forgot to close one of your functions. One `});` is missing.

Comment: @bipen: This is what need.first when user select one option from list, it should add new selection list. then if user select option from NEWLY added list it should add again one selection menu. and I need to change selection list id dynamically. is it possible?

Comment: @bipen:opposite of that one. that means it should add new option menu for last selection menu

Comment: @bipen: Aren't there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to duplicate the original one? have a see at this http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/jJknp/

```
$(document).on('change', '.target', function () {
    $(this).after($(this).clone());
});
```

If you only want to add when last `select` is selected, try this http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/jJknp/2/

```
$(document).on('change', '.target', function () {
    if ($(this).is($('.target:last'))) {
        $(this).after($(this).clone());
    }
});
```

If you want to add a differenct `select`, change `$(this).clone()` to what you want, but add `.target` class to it

This will add 2 to new `select`, http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/jJknp/3/

```
$(document).on('change', '.target', function () {
    if ($(this).is($('.target:last'))) {
        var clone = $(this).clone();
        clone.children('option').each(function () {
            $(this).val(+($(this).val()) + 2);
        });
        $(this).after(clone);
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not need to duplicate. i just only need to add new selection menu only for option select for last add selection menu not for the other selection menu

Comment: thanks for your effort. but here I need to add new values like option 3 and option 4. can I do that in clone ?

Comment: Do you just want to change the `value`?

Comment: yes. change the values and the selection menu id. can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would have 3 visible `<select>` where the 2nd and 3rd one has all `<option>` in different `<optgroup>` based on 1st and 2nd choise. Have a css `display: none` for these `<optgroup>` and store `data-select-value` with the `ID` or association of the values.

Then [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MLJwn/):

```
$(function() {
    var selector = {
        first_select : '#second_select',
        second_select : '#third_select'
    }
    $('#first_select, #second_select').bind('change', function() {
        var h = $(this).val();
        if (h) {
            $(selector[$(this).attr('id')]).find('> optgroup').each(function() {
                $(this).toggle(h == $(this).data('select-value'))
                    .attr('disabled', (h != $(this).data('select-value')));
            });
            $(selector[$(this).attr('id')]).find('option:visible').eq(0).attr('selected', true);
            $(selector[$(this).attr('id')]).show();
        }
    });
});
```

This example asumes that you have:

```
<select id="first_select">
    <option value="">Pick</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
<select id="second_select">
    <optgroup data-select-value="1">
        <option value="1_1">Choises appeares</option>
        <option value="1_2">More choises</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<select id="third_select">
    <optgroup data-select-value="1_1">
        <option value="1_1_1">Trippin' choises</option>
        <option value="1_1_2">So many choises</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup data-select-value="1_2">
        <option value="1_2_1">Choises!!</option>
        <option value="1_2_2">God, they're everywhere!</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<style type="text/css">
    #second_select, 
    #third_select {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but this not what I'm looking for. T need add selection menu dynamically not pre defined

Comment: I can render them visible upon select and it would suit your case. Will rewrite this.

Comment: This is I'm going to use in django template. there I didn't know number of selection filed that I have to use. it depends on the database. so that is why I need dynamic selection filed. I think you got what I'm saying

Comment: I added a jsFiddle for this that works. As long as it's not a really large set of selection, you'd do just fine constructing `<option>` based on database content with this approach.

Comment: sometimes this structure can be consist of 10, 15 selection menu. can you still recommend this method?

Comment: You mean that a user can have to choose through a depth up to 15 values? That sounds from a UI perspective as quite the headache.